# Will a Noctua NH-D15 fit inside a bitfenix colossus full tower?

Tags: fan, case

Building my first PC and wanted to make sure they will cooperate before purchasing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dimensions of the case are given  and the product website.  The specifications of the NH-D15 are given on the product website.  What has your research determined after looking at both specifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case:

> Dimensions (WxHxD)  **245 x 558 x 582 mm** (ATX Full Tower)

NH-D15:

> Height (without fan)  160 mm  
>  Width (without fan)  150 mm  
>   Depth (without fan)  135 mm 
>   Dimensions (without fan) (WxHxD) **150 X 160 X 135 mm**
>
> Height (with fan)  165 mm 
>   Width (with fan)  150 mm 
>  Depth (with fan)  161 mm 
>   Dimensions (with fan) (WxHxD) **150 X 165 X 161 mm**

Based on this specifications the NH-D15 should be able to fit.

[BitFenix Colossus](http://www.bitfenix.com/global/en/products/chassis/colossus)

[Noctua NH-D15](http://www.noctua.at/main.php?show=productview&products_id=68&lng=en&set=1)

Comment: Thanks! I did go to the websites earlier and checked the dimensions (I'm not that lazy), but did not know how much space should be left aside for the mobo and other stuff, and that's why I asked here. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: @user4492719 - Seems like you should have done more research because your explanation does not explain match what your question was.  If you knew if it would fit I am not sure what the question is honestly.

Comment: Because the fan is not the only thing inside (there are a lot of parts haha) so I didn't know how much space does a motherboard take on the case and all of the other stuff. AND I wanted to be sure that it fits so I don't waste my money on a part that wouldn't fit.